# Replacing sigmoid activation with custom activation

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am experimenting replacing the Keras sigmoid function with a piecewise linear function defined as:

```
def custom_activation_4(x):
if x < -6:
    return 0
elif x >= -6 and x < -4:
    return (0.0078*x + 0.049)
elif x >= -4 and x < 0:
    return (0.1205*x + 0.5)
elif x >= 0 and x < 4:
    return (0.1205*x + 0.5)
elif x >= 4 and x < 6:
    return (0.0078*x + 0.951)
else:
    return 1;
```

When I try to run this as:

```
classifier_4.add(Dense(output_dim = 18, init = 'uniform', activation = custom_activation_4, input_dim = 9))
```

The compiler throws an error saying:

```
Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed.
```

I researched this and learned that, I am treating the variable x as a simple python variable whereas it is a tensor. That is the reason it cannot be treated like a simple boolean variable. I also tried using the **tensorflow cond** method. How to treat and use x as tensor here? Thanks a ton in advance for all the help.

Comment: You need to use something like `tf.cond` instead of `if` statements. Something like `v = tf.cond(x<-6, 0, 0.0078*x + 0.049)`. You may need to use `from keras import backend as K` and then use `K.cond` instead of `tf.cond`.

Comment: but `tf.cond` will not give the if else kind of check right? `tf.cond(x<-6, 0, 0.0078*x + 0.049)` here if x is greater than -6 and also greater than -4 it will still give `0.0078*x + 0.049` instead of `0.1205*x + 0.5`. Any ideas?

Comment: That's only an example, not the complete code of course. You have multiple conditions so you need to nest them together, like `tf.cond(x<-6, 0, tf.cond(x<-4, 0.0078*x + 0.049, tf.cond(x<0, 0.1205*x + 0.5, tf.cond(blablabla))))`

Comment: @user12075 yeah thanks I wrote the same thing. Thanks for a quick reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your custom activation is written as a function of a single floating point number but you want to apply it to a whole tensor. The best way to do that is to use `tf.where`. Something like

```
def custom_activation_4(x):
  orig = x
  x = tf.where(orig < -6, tf.zeros_like(x), x)
  x = tf.where(orig >= -6 and orig < -4, (0.0078*x + 0.049), x)
  x = tf.where(orig >= -4 and orig < 0, (0.1205*x + 0.5), x)
  x = tf.where(orig >= 0 and orig < 4, (0.1205*x + 0.5), x)
  x = tf.where(orig  >= 4 and orig < 6, (0.0078*x + 0.951), x)
  return tf.where(orig >= 6, 1, x)
```

Comment: thank you so much for this brilliant answer. I so wish I had gotten this two days ago. I managed to do the function using Keras backend and tensor arithmetic.

Comment: In this solution, each and every time the x is getting updated and the new x value is found which is not right. Once the x value is updated it should go to the return line and then exit from the function.

Answer (score 2):

I tested the code in the answer because I intend to write a similar activation function, yet the following error happened

```py
raise TypeError("Using a tf.Tensor as a Python bool is not allowed. " TypeError: Using a tf.Tensor as a Python bool is not allowed. Use if t is not None: instead of if t: to test if a tensor is defined, and use TensorFlow ops such as tf.cond to execute subgraphs conditioned on the value of a tensor
```

The reason is that we cannot use Python logical operators on tf.Tensor. So I did some search in tf doc, and it turns out that we have to use theirs like this, which is my code, yet very very similar to yours.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

class QPWC(Layer):


    def __init__(self, sharp=100, **kwargs):
        super(QPWC, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.supports_masking = True
        self.sharp = K.cast_to_floatx(sharp)

    def call(self, inputs):

        orig = inputs
        inputs = tf.where(orig <= 0.0, tf.zeros_like(inputs), inputs)
        inputs = tf.where(tf.math.logical_and(tf.greater(orig, 0), tf.less(orig, 0.25)), 0.25 / (1+tf.exp(-self.sharp*((inputs-0.125)/0.5))), inputs)
        inputs = tf.where(tf.math.logical_and(tf.greater(orig, 0.25), tf.less(orig, 0.5)), 0.25 / (1+tf.exp(-self.sharp*((inputs-0.5)/0.5))) + 0.25, inputs)
        inputs = tf.where(tf.math.logical_and(tf.greater(orig, 0.5), tf.less(orig, 0.75)), 0.25 / (1+tf.exp(-self.sharp*((inputs-0.75)/0.5))) + 0.5, inputs)
        return  tf.where(tf.greater(orig, 0.75), tf.ones_like(inputs), inputs)


    def get_config(self):
        config = {'sharp': float(self.sharp)}
        base_config = super(QPWC, self).get_config()
        return dict(list(base_config.items()) + list(config.items()))

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape
```